# Mac : Launch command when device connected by bluetooth

Tags: macos, bluetooth, macos-sierra, launchd

I would like to launch a shell command when a specific external bluetooth device is connected to my Mac.

A nice way (without installing third party software) to do that is by adding a plist file in ~/Library/LaunchAgents

On [this page](https://github.com/rimar/wifi-location-changer/), there is an example of launching an event when the wifi connects to a specific location. It is done by watching a specific file :

```
<key>WatchPaths</key>
<array>
   <string>/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.airport.preferences.plist</string>
</array>
```

Do you think it'd possible to do the same with bluetooth events ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I found the /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist file. But this file changes a little too much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file in ~/Library/LaunchAgents containing :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>

    <key>Label</key>
    <string>Smartcard reader</string>

    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/USERNAME/Library/Scripts/script.bash</string>
    </array>

    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist</string>
    </array>

</dict>
</plist>
```

And in /Users/USERNAME/Library/Scripts/script.bash we can test if the connected device is the right one :

```
if [ $(system_profiler SPBluetoothDataType | grep "Smart Reader 2501" | wc -l) -eq 1 ] ; then
    echo "Smartcard connected"
fi
```

Launch the service using

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/yourscript
```

Comment: I don't believe the "test" code is enough. The system_profiler output will contain the name of the device even if it's not connected. You'd need to parse the output or run some AppleScript. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/48327866/6962.

Comment: I can't confirm that this works on MacOS 12 using a node js file watcher. Even removing a bluetooth device doesn't trigger a change event. Diffing them in the 2 states doesn't show any difference either.

Comment: On macOS 12, this test works, `system_profiler SPBluetoothDataType | sed '/<DEVICE_NAME>/q' | grep 'Not Connected:'`, but the plist file watching `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist` does not work (never triggered).