# AppleScript IOBluetooth issue, but only when exported as an app

Tags: bluetooth, applescript

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/57776820/2654603 I am using the `IOBluetooth` framework to detect disconnect/reconnect of my keyboard, such that switching it to a second host triggers changing the display input to that host as well.

When I run it in Script Editor it detects both connected and disconnected states as I switch back and forth. When I export it as an App (with Run-only) and run it, it starts out detecting the correct state. However once the keyboard has disconnected and later reconnects it never detects the connected state again.

If it matters, I'm on Catalina (10.15.7) on a 2019 MacBook Pro.

```
use framework "IOBluetooth"
use scripting additions

property lastStatus : true

set debug to true
set myKeyboard to "Keychron"

repeat
    set kbStatus to isDeviceConnected(myKeyboard)
    if kbStatus is not equal to lastStatus then
        if debug is false then
            if kbStatus is true then
                do shell script "/usr/local/bin/ddcctl -d 1 -i 27"
            else
                do shell script "/usr/local/bin/ddcctl -d 1 -i 17"
            end if
        else
            log "Status changed to " & kbStatus
        end if
        set lastStatus to kbStatus
    end if
    delay 1
end repeat

on isDeviceConnected(substring)
    repeat with device in (current application's IOBluetoothDevice's pairedDevices() as list)
        if (device's nameOrAddress as string) contains substring then
            if device's isConnected then
                return true
            else
                return false
            end if
        end if
    end repeat
    
    return false
end isDeviceConnected
```

Edit: I have inserted lots of debug log messages in various places. When it fails to detect the reconnect, it is still matching my keyboard name in the `pairedDevices()` list, just not as connected.

Comment: Couple of issues/questions before I give an explicit answer. First, if you're using a stay-open applescript app you should use an idle handler, not an endless repeat loop. It's more efficient, and it makes the app easier to work with. Second, shouldn't you be using empty parens on `nameOrAddress()` and `isConnected()`? That could be the failure right there. But see my next comment...

Comment: the IOBluetoothDevice class has explicit methods for setting up notifications — `+ registerForConnectNotifications:selector:` and `- registerForDisconnectNotification:selector:`. Why do the trouble of polling when you can ask the system to notify you of connects/disconnects? Let me know which way you want to jump on this and I'll fix up the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you didn't add parentheses to some of your objC methods, specifically: `nameOrAddress()` and `isConnected()`.  I'll add that it's far better to use an idle loop than an endless repeat loop. That would look like this:

```
property lastStatus : true
property debug : true
property myKeyboard : "Keychron"

on idle
    set kbStatus to isDeviceConnected(myKeyboard)
    if kbStatus is not equal to lastStatus then
        if debug is false then
            if kbStatus is true then
                do shell script "/usr/local/bin/ddcctl -d 1 -i 27"
            else
                do shell script "/usr/local/bin/ddcctl -d 1 -i 17"
            end if
        else
            log "Status changed to " & kbStatus
        end if
        set lastStatus to kbStatus
    end if
    return 1
end idle
```

**But set all that aside**, because I think the best solution is to use the IOBluetoothDevice methods for registering observers. That way your app will sleep quietly in the background until it gets a notification that a device has been connected or disconnected. Copy the following script into Script Editor:

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite 10.10 or later
use framework "IOBluetooth"
use scripting additions

property IOBluetoothDevice : class "IOBluetoothDevice"

property myKeyboard : "Keychron"

property connectionNotifObj : missing value
property disconnectionNotifObj : missing value

on run
    try
        set connectionNotifObj to IOBluetoothDevice's registerForConnectNotifications:me selector:"didConnectNotif:forDevice:"
    on error errstr
        display dialog errstr
    end try
end run

on quit
    try
        connectionNotifObj's unregister()
    end try
    set connectionNotifObj to missing value
    continue quit
end quit

on didConnectNotif:notif forDevice:dev
    if (dev's nameOrAddress() as text) contains myKeyboard then
        set disconnectionNotifObj to (dev's registerForDisconnectNotification:me selector:"didDisconnectNotif:forDevice:")
    end if
end didConnectNotif:forDevice:

on didDisconnectNotif:notif forDevice:dev
    if (dev's nameOrAddress() as string) contains myKeyboard then
        try
            disconnectionNotifObj's unregister()
        end try
        set disconnectionNotifObj to missing value
    end if
end didDisconnectNotif:forDevice:
```

Save the script as an application — make sure you click the `stay open after run handler` checkbox so the script app doesn't auto-quit — and you should be good to go.

If you want the script app to be invisible to the Dock and App Picker, run the following command in terminal:

```
defaults write '/path/to/$name.app/Contents/Info.plist' LSUIElement -bool yes
```

Of course, that makes quitting it manually a bit more of a headache (you'll have to use Terminal or Activity Monitor to see it running), but it's visually more pleasing.

Comment: I will give all of these a try, because even if I do go for a different approach I want to know why this was broken. I agree your solution is more elegant, I'm just not familiar enough with AppleScript to have known about it. All that said, I still don't understand why it's only broken as an app vs running from Script Editor. :|

Comment: @cfiske: As I remember, properties in AppleScript apps were never reliably persistent (though I did some testing and it seems as though they've fixed it some; at least, I can't seem to generate the troubles I used to have). If I have to keep a persistent property with AppleScriptObjC, I've gotten in the habit of using NSUserDefaults to make a standard property list. but let me test your script more thoroughly and see if I can replicate the problem.

Comment: @cfiske: OK, the problem has something to do with using the endless repeat loop. I tested a number of things, but the problem didn't go away until I shifted the script to using an `on idle` handler. Don't ask me *why* that's the case; I don't know, except to note that AppleScript isn't threaded, so using an endless repeat loop obviously is preventing the system from updating the properties or querying bluetooth.

Comment: For whatever reason I could not get the idle loop approach to work at all, but with a few tweaks your observer approach works like a charm. (Edit: I failed to include the top few lines in my paste so got some errors, now resolved) Thanks for the help and info!

Comment: @cfiske: really? if you have the first property statement — `property IOBluetoothDevice : class "IOBluetoothDevice"` — that shouldn't be the case. But as long as it works... 

Comment: Yeah that's one of those top few lines I missed (see edit in my comment). Your code was spot on, I just had to add the bits to take the appropriate action in each case.